# tkz-euclide changing labels and size (triangle, inscribed circle)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

A friend of me Torbjørn, showed me how to build the image below using tikz

[image: Inscribed circle and whatnot]

with the following code.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \begin{document}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 I en $\Delta ABC$ er $\angle A = 90^{\circ}$ En sirkel med sentrum i 
 $S$ er innskrevet i trekanten. Sidene $AC$ og $BC$ tangerer sirkelen
 i punktene $D$ og $E$. Linjen gjennom $B$ og $S$ skjærer $DE$ i $F$. \\
 \\
 Se skissen til høyre. \\
 \\
 Du får oppgitt at $DC=EC$.\\
 \\
 Vi setter $\angle ABC = v, \: \angle BCU = u, \: $ og $\angle BFE=x$\\
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
   \tkzInit[ymin=-1,ymax=5,xmin=-1,xmax=5]
   \tkzClip 
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
   \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,4){C}
   \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
     \tkzGetPoint{S}
     \tkzGetLength{rSN}
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
   \tkzDrawCircle[R](S,\rSN pt)
   \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
   \tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(S,\rSN pt) \tkzGetFirstPoint{D}
   \tkzInterLC[R](B,C)(S,\rSN pt) \tkzGetFirstPoint{E}
   \tkzInterLL(B,S)(D,E) \tkzGetPoint{F}
   \tkzDrawPoints(D,E,F,S)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,red](D,E)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,violet](B,F)
   \tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above left](C,F)
   \tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)
   \tkzLabelPoints[below left](A,S)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above right](E)
   \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4 cm](B,F,E)
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](B,F,E){\large $x$}
   \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,A,C)
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

Using geogebra, I was able to prduce a simmilar looking image, as below

[image: Geogebra image of the same figure]

My question is. How can I transform my tikz image into looking more like the geogebra image? The point in S should be black, not violet, and one should keep the angle A. (I had problems both changing the color of the inscribed circle, changing the size of the labels, and changing the color of the points.)

I think that was it for now. Alas the tikz image works better without the minipages.

Comment: Please post a separate question for a single problem. That's how the site works, and how other users can find solutions to their problems later here. Please don't mix a bundle of questions just because they belong together for your special case.

Comment: Okay =) I just thought I would be noisy asking tons of questions here in a row, simpler to ask in a single post. Will update my post accordingly.

Comment: A good question would be: "How can I increase the size of all labels in a TikZ picture?" together with your code. Another one "How can I change color and thickness of a TikZ circle?" It would be great if you would try to create good questions for the public, not just "please solve this bunch of issues for me".

Comment: True, noise doesn't help :) but good, well formulated questions do, they are the foundation of the site. From answers to good questions we built a knowledge base.

Comment: At least I tried changing my post =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use options when drawing, such as

```
\tkzDrawCircle[R,very thick](S,\rSN pt)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,shape=circle,fill=black](D,E,F,S)
```

or set styles, such as by `\tkzSetUpPoint` and `\tkzSetUpLine`, which are explained in the tkz-euclide manual.

Regarding the labels, you could set their style via an option to the `tikzpicture` or by `\tikzset`, such as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,label style/.style={font=\Large}]
```

By this, the picture changes to

[image: tikz picture]

Answer (score 6):

Stefan'answer is correct. I would like only elaborate some methods. First you can use generally  most of the tikz's options, then specific macro for an object (here points) have two versions : `tkzDrawPoint`,and `tkzDrawPoints`. If all points use the same style (this is recommended) then you can use `tkzDrawPoints` else you need to use the first version. Finally I prefer to draw the points at the end of the code.

With your code the result is :

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
   \tkzInit[ymin=-1,ymax=5,xmin=-1,xmax=5]
   \tkzClip 
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
   \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,4){C}
   \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
   \tkzGetPoint{S}
   \tkzGetLength{rSN}
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
   \tkzDrawCircle[R](S,\rSN pt)
   \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
   \tkzInterLC[R](A,C)(S,\rSN pt) \tkzGetFirstPoint{D}
   \tkzInterLC[R](B,C)(S,\rSN pt) \tkzGetFirstPoint{E}
   \tkzInterLL(B,S)(D,E) \tkzGetPoint{F}
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,red](D,E)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,violet](B,F)
   \tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above left](C,F)
   \tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)
   \tkzLabelPoints[below left](A,S)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above right](E)
   \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4 cm](B,F,E)
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](B,F,E){\large $x$}
   \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,A,C)
   \tkzDrawPoints(D,E)      
   \tkzDrawPoint[color=black,fill=black](F)  
   \tkzDrawPoint[color=black,fill=violet](S)  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]